# HTML display image on top-left of page

Tags: html, css, image

I want to display an image on the top-left corner of my page. There should be a space of 10 pixels to the top and a space of 10 pixels to the left. I searched the web and found two possible answers. The first one uses the `margin` property while the second `top` and `left` with `position: absolute;`:

```
<body>
<img src="x.jpg" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
</body>
```

and

```
<body>
<img src="x.jpg" style="top: 10px; left: 10px; position: absolute;">
</body>
```

Both seem to work but is there any difference between them? Which one should I use?

Comment: what does the rest of the page look like? is it just the image and nothing else?

Comment: I would go with option 1 simply because if it's just a standalone image you don't need it to break out of the flow of the document. Why would you need it to go with option 2 to further complicate things in the future with other elements overlaying with it etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the situation. If you use margin, then the rest of the page will notice that the image exists, and move (if they overlap). If you use `position: absolute;` then the rest of the page *won't* notice that it exists, and will ignore it, and, if it collides with the image, then it will go under.

Example using absolute positioning:

```css
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.jamfoo.com/chat/smiley.png" class="absolute">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sit amet nisi nec est tristique efficitur. Fusce ut dapibus lorem. Mauris semper orci non magna malesuada tristique. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In posuere arcu a turpis aliquam, vel ultrices ligula egestas. Quisque congue eu sem et porta. Pellentesque velit enim, tristique in felis nec, ornare pretium urna. Etiam ipsum turpis, commodo non augue ac, bibendum condimentum ipsum. Etiam tristique neque volutpat, luctus purus nec, tempus elit. Vestibulum rhoncus bibendum erat, sed malesuada quam convallis vel. Ut bibendum scelerisque ex, a fringilla magna euismod non. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec euismod consequat turpis, eu tincidunt lacus fermentum eu. Nam egestas nibh quis sapien posuere egestas. </p>
```

Example using margin:

```css
.margin {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.jamfoo.com/chat/smiley.png" class="margin">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sit amet nisi nec est tristique efficitur. Fusce ut dapibus lorem. Mauris semper orci non magna malesuada tristique. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In posuere arcu a turpis aliquam, vel ultrices ligula egestas. Quisque congue eu sem et porta. Pellentesque velit enim, tristique in felis nec, ornare pretium urna. Etiam ipsum turpis, commodo non augue ac, bibendum condimentum ipsum. Etiam tristique neque volutpat, luctus purus nec, tempus elit. Vestibulum rhoncus bibendum erat, sed malesuada quam convallis vel. Ut bibendum scelerisque ex, a fringilla magna euismod non. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec euismod consequat turpis, eu tincidunt lacus fermentum eu. Nam egestas nibh quis sapien posuere egestas. </p>
```

Also note that if you use `position: absolute;` then the img will be 10px down and 10px left from the top/left *of the page*, but if you use margin, then it will be 10px down and 10px left from the top/left *of its parent*. For example;

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.margin {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
.no-margin {
  background-color: red;
}
.absolute {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

/* this style can be ignored */
span.absolute {
  left: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
  <img src="http://www.jamfoo.com/chat/smiley.png" class="margin">
  <span class="margin">This example uses margin</span>
</div>
<div class="blue">
  <img src="http://www.jamfoo.com/chat/smiley.png" class="no-margin">
  <span class="no-margin">This example uses no margin</span>
</div>
<div class="blue">
  <img src="http://www.jamfoo.com/chat/smiley.png" class="absolute">
  <span class="absolute">This example uses absolute positioning, and is at the top of the page, even though it is after the other two divs.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which one to use is up to you. The difference is that the absolutely positioned one will remove the image from the flow of the document and the other elements will act like it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Rob It depends on the OP's HTML and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the first option because you won't have to worry about it's absolute position in the future.
As an example, if you go for the 2nd option, other ellements will go in it and you will have to give them margins.
I hope this helped you !